# AttributeError at /admin/orders2/order/11/change/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: python, django

Everything is working fine in my frontend, this problem is occurring when I'm trying to access the orders in my admin panel. In my console it also says:

`cursor.close()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.`

I tried to figure out where the problem was, but failed. Why is this throwing an error?
Can anyone please help me solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

My models.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.user.username
```

My admin.py:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'ordered', 'being_delivered', 'received', 'refund_requested',
    'refund_granted', 'shipping_address', 'billing_address', 'payment', 'coupon']
    list_filter = ['ordered', 'being_delivered', 'received', 'refund_requested', 'refund_granted']
    list_display_links = ['user', 'shipping_address', 'billing_address', 'payment', 'coupon']
    search_fields = ['user__username', 'ref_code']

admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

Comment: Can you add the full traceback?

Comment: Please post the views.py related to the Order model.

Comment: The views are very big

Comment: @Abrar change `def __str__(self):` section where you've written `return self.user.username`. change this one to `return str(self.id)`. Not sure if it's fix it, but give it a go.

Comment: Now it says: ```__str__ returned non-string (type int)```

Comment: Sorry change from `return self.id` to `return str(self.id)`. Edited above comment too.

Comment: But why did it not have a username? It showed that it had a username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the following models.py-

From:

```
def __str__(self):
   return self.user.username
```

To:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

**Reason:** It's better not to return `__str__` method as foreign key for models. A conflict happens in case `if username is None`, what'll then happen.